# Finding max number in a list

Tags: python

I'm following a Python tutorial and I'm making a simple function for finding the max number in a list. The function works with small numbers but gets weird when I use larger numbers. I tried inputting 5 random numbers: 2342,231,656,423,132 and it returns 656 as the max number. Any suggestions?

```
def find_max(numbers):
    max = numbers[0]
    for number in numbers:
        print("The current max is: ", max)
        if number > max:
            max = number

    return max
```

Comment: please don't use `max` as your variable name, use `my_max` or something else instead

Comment: See the difference between `max(9, 10)` and `max('9', '10')` (or in your example, the difference between`9 > 10` and `'9' > '10'`)

Comment: Just adding to @Mahrkeenerh comment: `max` is actually a method in Python. Look here how to use it: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_max.htm

Comment: running your code on my machine returns 2342 are you sure you are calling the function as you belive

Comment: @wovano can you explain what's happening with the strings?

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh, OP didn't create a [mre] (as is required), but I guess the code uses `input()` so it compares strings instead of ints. And obviously, strings are sorted alphabetically, not numerically.

Comment: @wovano yeah, I know that, I just wasn't sure why the second `max('9', '10')` would return '9', but thinking about it a little, It's probably comparing them as strings, so first element with first and so on. Was a little confused with it for a second

Comment: Thanks guys! I got it now, I was comparing strings instead of integers. Yeah I know max is a built in funciton, this youtube guide still said this was a good practice for beginners. Oh well! :)

Comment: @gogosimba YouTube guides are very often wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply `return max(numbers)` :

```
def find_max(numbers):
    return max(numbers)
find_max([2342, 231, 656, 423, 132])
>>> 2342
```

Comment: You can directly use the function without defining a new one.

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: This does not solve the problem of the OP. It does the same thing as the original code.

Comment: Because there is no problem to solve, his code is working as expected. I'm just pointing out he can use max function to save time.